# 16.04 - Slow Kernel Boot (LVM issue)

Tags: boot, kernel, 16.04, lvm

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 my system boot slow down consistently

To analyze the cause I used this command.

```
systemd-analyze plot > boot.xml
google-chrome ./boot.xml
```

I have found out `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` was taking 7s alone so I have disabled it.

```
systemctl mask NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Now the result of `systemd-analyze plot` show that my kernel boot time is the main cause:

> Startup finished in 18.552s (kernel) + 4.704s (userspace) = 23.256s

The whole system use to boot in 10/15s no it take 18s only for the kernel

How can I found out the reason for 18s kernel boot time ?

**UPDATE**

I used @Nick suggestion `dmesg > boot.txt` and I was able to find out the bottleneck points

```
[    2.771745] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    7.255226] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   18.512253] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

It looks there is some issue with the mounting part and maybe to LVM ...

Here my `fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=aa8cef14-44d2-43e4-be99-e2e826636e6b /boot           ext2    defaults  0       2

#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1      none    swap        sw      0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1  none        swap    sw          0 0
/dev/ubuntu-vg/usr      /usr        ext4    defaults    1 2
/dev/ubuntu-vg/opt      /opt        ext4    defaults    1 2
/dev/ubuntu-vg/home     /home       ext4    defaults    1 2
/dev/ubuntu-vg/web      /var/www/   ext4    defaults    1 2

/var/www/mysql         /var/lib/mysql/  none    bind
```

Is this a bug ?
Any solution/workaround ?

Comment: If you run `dmesg > boot.txt` immediately after booting your computer, you can examine the newly-created `boot.txt` to see the individual boot steps with their timestamps.

Comment: thx see my update

Comment: @Postadelmaga it will be great if you post answer and mark as solved :)

Comment: @MohamedSlama I will when I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

With `systemd` do not separate anymore / and /usr

More informations here https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/

Comment: should I remove `.../usr` line ?

Comment: oh no ! do not touch `/etc/fstab` if you don't know what you do.